# Force Chrome Extension version change via Group Policy

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that is listed as Private on the Webstore because I need different customers to be able to be on different versions of the extension at the same time. I am trying to use Group Policy to allow customers to force Chrome to install the extension on all of their user's machines (connected by an Active Directory Domain). As described here:

http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist

I have this process mostly working but with one big catch. I cannot get Chrome to update the extension in place without first uninstalling the extension altogether.

Specifically: While Chrome is running, I can use Group policy to install Version 1 of an extension, then uninstall it, then install Version 2 of the same extension. However, when I install Version 1, then point the update.xml file to Version 2 of the .crx (or even change the policy to a whole new update.xml pointing to Version 2) the extension will stay at Version 1 and will not install Version 2.

Here is what I have tried so far with no success:
After going to Chrome://policy and confirming that the new GPO pointing to Version 2 of the extension is recognized by Chrome:

I have tried restarting Chrome.

I have tried going to chrome://extensions, checking "Developer Mode, and clicking the "Update Extension Now" button.

I have tried launching Chrome from command line with the extensions-update-frequency parameter set to 30, 60, and 300 seconds.

I have tried leaving for lunch after setting the policy with Chrome running and not touching it or letting the computer lock for >2 hours hoping it would automatically update given time.

For all of these, Version 1 of the extension remains installed. I have triple checked that the new policy is pointing to a valid Version 2 of the extension (and this is confirmed because Version 2 will install if I disable the policy first then enable it pointing to Version 2).

Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Both versions of the extension that I'm trying to get installed have been signed from the Chrome Web Store and have the same extension ID string.

Answer (score 0):

make sure version number is bigger.

Manifest - Version

One to four dot-separated integers identifying the version of this extension. A couple of rules apply to the integers: they must be between 0 and 65535, inclusive, and non-zero integers can't start with 0. For example, 99999 and 032 are both invalid.

Here are some examples of valid versions:

```
"version": "1"
"version": "1.0"
"version": "2.10.2"
"version": "3.1.2.4567"
```

The autoupdate system compares versions to determine whether an installed extension needs to be updated. If the published extension has a newer version string than the installed extension, then the extension is automatically updated.

The comparison starts with the leftmost integers. If those integers are equal, the integers to the right are compared, and so on. For example, 1.2.0 is a newer version than 1.1.9.9999.

A missing integer is equal to zero. For example, 1.1.9.9999 is newer than 1.1.

For more information, see Autoupdating.
Version Name

In addition to the version field, which is used for update purposes, version_name can be set to a descriptive version string and will be used for display purposes if present.

Here are some examples of version names:

```
"version_name": "1.0 beta"
"version_name": "build rc2"
"version_name": "3.1.2.4567"
```

If no version_name is present, the version field will be used for display purposes as well.